# Sed to find line numbers with regular expressions

Tags: sed

I am trying to use unix sed command to find line numbers that match a particular regular expression. The pattern of my file is below

```
A<20 spaces>
<something>
<something>
..
..
A<20 spaces>
<soemthing>
<something>
```

I need all the line numbers of `A<20 spaces>`

I used `sed -n '/A[ ]{20}/'= <file_name>` but it does not work. If I manually type in twenty spaces it does work.

Can some one please tweak the above command to make it work.

Comment: Why don't you simply use `egrep -l "A[ ]{20}"` ?

Answer (score 5):

The braces in the expression need to be escaped with backslashes:

```
% sed -n '/A[ ]\{20\}/=' test.txt
1
6
```

An alternative would be to use [`-E`](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html#BRE-vs-ERE) to interpret regular expressions as extended (modern) regular expressions:

```
% sed -nE '/A[ ]{20}/=' test.txt 
1
6
```

Or potentially use `grep` instead, which takes fewer characters to specify the same search:

```
% grep -n 'A[ ]\{20\}' test.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

The correct syntax would be `/A \{20\}/` (and I'm failing to understand where you got your syntax from).

**edit: repeat a space, not an `A`.  not my day**

Comment: @venu: Welcome to StackOverflow. "It worked perfect (*sic*.)" is best expressed [by clicking on the check box outline to the left of the answer](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#howtoask) that helped you most.

Answer (score 0):

use the `-E` or the `-r` switch for extended regexp

Answer (score 0):

just to be sur of the content request is answered because it literraly mean "20 spaces" and not Twenty " " char that everyone understand due to the sed line sample failing (i guess this the good one so other reply are fine in this case)

```
sed -n "/<20 spaces>/ =" file_name
```